# Equality of Line Integrals for One Forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, line-integrals

I saw a post about how if the equality between integrals of two functions f and g holds over any domain V, then it implies an equality of the integrands too, so f=g. Can we extend this idea to C1 one forms on Rn? If we have two C1 1-forms that have the same line integral along every piecewise smooth curve Ψ from [a,b] to Rn, then does this imply the one forms are equal too?

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question. Yes. Suppose $\omega,\eta$ are $1$-forms on $\Bbb R^n$ and they are not equal at some point $p$. Then (by continuity) there is a neighborhood of $p$ on which they are not equal. By subtracting, we reduce to the case of a single $1$-form $\phi$ which is nonzero at $p$, and therefore nonzero on some neighborhood. Look at the hyperplane $\Pi = \{v\in\Bbb R^n: \phi(p)(v) = 0\}$. $\Pi$ divides $\Bbb R^n$ into two halves, if you like; choose a $w\in\Bbb R^n$ on the positive side of $\Pi$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be suitably small. If you let $\Psi$ be the line segment from $p$ to $p+\epsilon w$, then I claim that $$\int_\Psi\phi > 0,$$
which settles your question (by taking the contrapositive). Can you finish the argument?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for contradiction that the difference of 2 differential 1-forms $(\omega - \widetilde{\omega}) \neq 0$ at $p \in A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Without loss of generality, let $(\omega_n - \widetilde{\omega}_n)$ be positive at $p$. By continuity of $(\omega - \widetilde{\omega})$, I can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $(\omega_n(x) - \widetilde{\omega}_n(x)) >0$ for all $x \in B(p; \epsilon)$. Now consider \begin{eqnarray*}
            \alpha: [0,1]:=I &\to& \mathbb{R}^n \\
            t &\mapsto& (1-t)\begin{pmatrix}
                p_1 \\
                \vdots\\
                p_{n-1}\\
                p_n
            \end{pmatrix} + t\begin{pmatrix}
                p_1\\
                \vdots \\
                p_{n-1}\\
                p_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2}
            \end{pmatrix} \text{ so } D\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
                0 \\
                \vdots \\
                0 \\
                \frac{\epsilon}{2}
            \end{pmatrix}
        \end{eqnarray*}

Let $Y_{\alpha}= \alpha(I)$ so that $(\omega_n(x) - \widetilde{\omega}_n(x))>0$ for all $x\in Y_{\alpha}$ since $Y_{\alpha} \subset B(p; \epsilon)$. Then \begin{eqnarray*}
            \int_{Y_{\alpha}}\omega - \widetilde{\omega} &=& \int_{Y_{\alpha}}(\omega_1 - \widetilde{\omega}_1)dx_1 + \ldots +  (\omega_{n-1} - \widetilde{\omega}_{n-1})dx_{n-1} + (\omega_{n} - \widetilde{\omega}_{n})dx_{n} \\
            &=& \int_{I}(\omega_1(\alpha) - \widetilde{\omega}_1(\alpha))D\alpha_1 + \ldots +  (\omega_{n-1}(\alpha) - \widetilde{\omega}_{n-1}(\alpha))D\alpha_{n-1} + (\omega_{n} - \widetilde{\omega}_{n})D\alpha_n\\
           &=& \int_I 0 + \ldots + 0 + (\omega_{n} - \widetilde{\omega}_{n}) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \int_I (\omega_{n} - \widetilde{\omega}_{n}) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2} >0
        \end{eqnarray*} which implies that $\displaystyle\int_{Y_\alpha} \omega \neq \int_{Y_{\alpha}}\widetilde{\omega}$ and contradicts our assumption.

To sum up, continuity is the key so that we can make integral of the forms along some special short curve non-zero.